# Is it possible to add more than 500 rows of data into a database in 1 query in SQLite in AIR 3.6 project?

Tags: flash, sqlite, air, insert

I'm creating iPad app in Flash (AIR 3.6).
I need to synchronize tons of data using SQLite database engine.
I'm receiving data from the server in JSON format which needs to be converted to Vector of data.

As far as I know Flash SQLite engine allows only 1 process of INSERT at a time, so I decided to add as much as I can in 1 query.
I'm using UNION ALL with INSERT but I encountered a limit of 500 unions after which SQLite engine refuses to cooperate.

Because of that I had to create a structure which adds up to 500 inserts with unions and runs until all of data will be inserted that way. For 2k+ rows it loops about 5times.
I tried to insert data 1 by 1 but it took like 300 times what it is taking right now.

Finally:
Is it possible to add more than 500 rows of data into a database in 1 query in SQLite in AIR 3.6 project?

**Edit:**

Using many INSERT in one transaction doesnt seems to work as:

```
var sql:String = "";
sql +=  "INSERT INTO TablicaTestowa (formTypeId,name,timestamp) VALUES ('abc2','nazwa2','sg535');"
sql +=  "INSERT INTO TablicaTestowa (formTypeId,name,timestamp) VALUES ('abc3','nazwa3','gwt5htbsd');"
sql +=  "INSERT INTO TablicaTestowa (formTypeId,name,timestamp) VALUES ('abc4','nazwa4','frtgwh3jwdsed');"
createStmt.text = sql;
createStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult2);
createStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, createError2);
createStmt.execute();
```

only adds the 1st values ('abc2','nazwa2','sg535). Or mayby im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a single `INSERT` query; you can wrap multiple `INSERT`s into one transaction to get similar performance.

Comment: No, I can't. Only the first INSERT works. Others seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can !

```
public void putAll(Context context, LinkedList<HANDLEDOBJECT> objects) {
    if (objects.size() < 1 || objects.get(0) == null)
        return;
    Log.i("Database", "Starting to insert objects to " + getTableName());

    List<String> insertCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
    int t = 0;
    while (t < objects.size()) {
        int k = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ").append(getTableName())
                .append("('k', 'v') ");
        for (t = t + 0; t < objects.size() && k < 450; t++) {
            k++;
            if (t % 450 != 0)
                sb.append("UNION ");
            sb.append("SELECT " + objects.get(t).getId())
                    .append(" AS k, ")
                    .append("'"
                            + GsonSerializer.getInstance().toJson(
                                    objects.get(t), getHandledObjectType())
                            + "'").append(" AS v ");

        }

        insertCommands.add(sb.toString());
    }

    for (String insertCommand : insertCommands)
        SQLiteClient.getConnetion(context).execSQL(insertCommand);

    Log.i("Database", "Successfully inserted " + t + " objects to "
            + getTableName() + "!!!");
}
```